# .dockerignore pattern to exclude files in all subdirectories

Tags: docker, dockerignore

How can I exclude python generated files like `*.pyc` in all subdirectories from the docker image?

I added `.dockerignore` at the root of the context directory:

```
# Ignore generated files
*.pyc
```

Alas `docker build` ignores this at least for subdirectories and copies the entire directory tree that looks like the following:

```
/contextdir/
|-- Dockerfile
\-- src/
    |-- a.py   # this is copied - all right
    \-- a.pyc  # this should be ignored, but is copied too. Why?
```

Answer (score 129, accepted):

Patterns like `*.pyc` are matched only at the beginning of the path, or for the files directly below the context directory, **but not recursively**. To make it work recursively the `**/` syntax must be used:

```
# Ignore generated files
**/*.pyc
```

The reference at [How to create a dockerignore file](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#dockerignore-file) doesn't put that clear enough.

Finally, I understood that trick. For some reason, I wasn't able to find any mention of this and haven't found any example `Dockerfile` with such construct, so documenting it here. Was it trivial for everybody else?

Comment: would it ignore those files as well in directories above?

Comment: `**.pyc` should do the same, (ignore all .pyc extension files) in all nested directories

Answer (score 11):

The [docs for .dockerignore](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#dockerignore-file) state that the .dockerignore file is interpreted as a list of patterns similar to the file globs of Unix shells. The pattern matching use's [Go's filepath matching logic](https://golang.org/pkg/path/filepath/#Match). The docs also cover the recursive pattern:

> Beyond Go’s filepath.Match rules, Docker also supports a special wildcard string ** that matches any number of directories (including zero). For example, **/*.go will exclude all files that end with .go that are found in all directories, including the root of the build context.

Comment: Yes, finally I figured that. The problem is, I'm personally not accustomed to Go's file matching rules and `**/` is quite common in other glob-like syntaxes, that do allow `*.extension` to be recursive.

Comment: Updated link to docs: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#dockerignore-file